# Simplifying logarithm expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Express as a single logarithm and​ simplify, if possible:

$$4\log_c(x)+4\log_c(y)−5\log_c(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_{c}\frac{y^4}{x}$$
You can look at the first 3 rules for operating with logs [here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/logrules.htm):

Comment: Always better to let the asker show some efforts thoughts first before helping. Just a tip for future answers.